# Class() vs self.__class__() when creating object?

Tags: python

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using `Class()` or `self.__class__()` to create a new object within a class?
Is one way generally preferred over the other?

Here is a contrived example of what I am talking about.

```
class Foo(object):                                                              
  def __init__(self, a):                                                        
    self.a = a                                                                  
                                                                                
  def __add__(self, other):                                                     
    return Foo(self.a + other.a)                                                
                                                                                
  def __str__(self):                                                            
    return str(self.a)                                                          
                                                                                
  def add1(self, b):                                                            
    return self + Foo(b)                                                        
                                                                                
  def add2(self, b):                                                            
    return self + self.__class__(b)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`self.__class__` will use the type of a subclass if you call that method from a subclass instance.

Using the class explicitly will use whatever class you explicitly specify (naturally)

e.g.:

```
class Foo(object):
    def create_new(self):
        return self.__class__()

    def create_new2(self):
        return Foo()

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

b = Bar()
c = b.create_new()
print(type(c))  # We got an instance of Bar
d = b.create_new2()
print(type(d))  # we got an instance of Foo
```

Of course, this example is pretty useless other than to demonstrate my point.  Using a classmethod here would be much better.

Comment: @mgilson I think, this works because `self` has a reference to a `Bar` object. That's why `self.__class__` points to `Bar` object.

Comment: @thefourtheye It works because `self.__class__` is always just the class that `self` is an instance of...